# can you limit the number of items in a recently-updated macro in confluence 2.9?

Tags: macros, confluence

i see in confluence 2.10, there is a max and maxresults parameter but i dont see these parameters in 2.9.1 or below.  Is there anyway to limit the results in these versions ?

Comment: Results of what? Is it a feed macro?

Comment: results of recently-updated pages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such parameters in 2.9, you could use the `{rss}` macro and display a confluence feed of recently updated content, but you would have to transmit [a username and password inside the url](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CONF29/Adding+a+username+and+password+to+Confluence+RSS+feeds), plus the resulting page will either simply display the list of page title (no space, no author nor date) or the complete diff/content for the page (a bit noisy).

A more practical way of limiting the number of results shownwould be to use the GET parameter `maxRecentlyUpdatedPageCount` which control the `{recently-updated}` macro behaviour.

In order to do that, you could use the `{redirect}` macro (it's in [a free plugin](https://plugins.atlassian.com/plugin/details/183)) on your page. Supposing your page is located at `http://confluence.example.come/display/SPACE/Page`, its source will look like (for 50 recently update items) :

```
{recently-updated}

{redirect:location=http://confluence.example.come/display/SPACE/Page?redirect=false&maxRecentlyUpdatedPageCount=50}
```

Note that it will display a slightly annoying information panel, warning you about the redirect. If you want to get rid of it, get your hands on the `{span}` macro ([free plugin](https://plugins.atlassian.com/plugin/details/247) as well), and change the markup of the page to :

```
{recently-updated}

{span:style=display:none;}
{redirect:location=http://confluence.example.come/display/SPACE/Page?redirect=false&maxRecentlyUpdatedPageCount=50}
{span}
```